# Copy cell data from MS Word table to Excel based on value of cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vbscript, microsoft-word-2016

I have a rather large Word questionnaire. It has several similar irregular (meaning some rows have merged cells and some do not) tables in it. I need to read each table for 3 specific values and take the response in the next cell and move it to a new excel spreadsheet so I can import that data into Access.

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False
objWord.DisplayAlerts = False
objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\TheRev\Desktop\AllObj.docx", False, True
Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveSheet

dstRow = 0
For Each tbl In objDoc.Tables
    For srcRow = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
        col = 0
        For Each cell In tbl.Rows(srcRow).Cells
            If cell = "Family number" then 
            wscript.echo "Found it"
        Else 
        col = col + 1
                objSheet.Cells(dstRow+srcRow, col).Value = Left(cell.Range.Text, Len(cell.Range.Text)-1)
        End If
        Next
    Next
    dstRow = dstRow + SrcRow
Next
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\TheRev\Desktop\SurveyResults.xlsx"
objExcel.Quit
```

Transforms all of my tables into the excel workbook. Not what I need.

What I need to do:

If the cell value is "Objective number", copy the next cell over's data (3.9.1) into the Excel spreadsheet's column A, then the data from 2 cells down (Technologies go here) into Excel's column B, and then the next cell down (Questions go here) into Excel Column C. Repeat until the end of the Word doc.

How would I do that?

[image: Screenshot of part of the questionnaire]

[Screenshot of complete questionnaire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWuyy.gif)

Test file for download. Right Click [Save As](https://files.engineering.com/download.aspx?folder=c460f9a3-9926-428a-9488-d5140af8f5c7&file=Upload1.docx).

Comment: Ick. Sorry the code didn't format right...

Comment: You might get more help if you post a link to one page of `testDocument.docx`

Comment: it's not mine. Put it in the question.

Comment: Sorry. Trying to get used to this format for a message board... Link added.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130971

Comment: You should create your test file as compatible w/ older versions of word if possible. Yours will not open in Word 2003.